# Unable to delete emails from a business email over IMAP (Gmail servers)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail, imap

I have an email addresse from a company that forwards all of them into Gmail (Imap). Now, in Outlook 2007, when I delete an email from that account, the email just get greyed out with a horizontal line on it but won't go out of the folder. It won't delete... is there a way to have those email deleter permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: [Deleting IMAP messages](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78755) . From what I remember about IMAP, most clients do not actually delete messages, they just mark them for deletion (probably that's what you see with the greyed out messages with horizontal line; I've seen this in Squirrel Mail). One needs to purge the marked for deletion messages afterwards. That might even be in the IMAP specifications. However, I am not sure about the Gmail or Outlook implementations of IMAP.

Comment: You're right about IMAP in general: Messages are merely marked for deletion until they're expunged.  Gmail has some extra wrinkles because the same message can show up in multiple folders, and some of the behavior is configurable.

Comment: Hi lupincho. I've tested it and when I move the email from the Inbox to the Trash folder, it disapear from the Inbox, which is good. When I go in Trash, and I delete the email from there, it doesn't permantly delete it, only put another line on it. Any clue?

Comment: @afrazier Any Idea how to configure Outlook 2007 to permanently delete those emails? I don't want to see those deleted emails to show anymore.

Comment: Don't have outlook to try, but you need to purge them: https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/purge-imap-items-marked-for-deletion-HP010080420.aspx

Comment: lupincho. You da man!!!!